# "deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds.",

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am getting `"deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds.", source: file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js (1185)` while running my cordova android app on genymotion android emulator.

What i have tried so far?

I have installed `cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.file` from CLI
And added `<preference name="AndroidPersistentFileLocation" value="Compatibility" />` to my `config.xml` file  still no luck,I am getting any proper solution for google.

I am new to `cordova`  What i have learned so far `deviceReady` is a function used fired after after `booting` of `application`.

Answer (score 1):

what is version cordova are you using?

```
<script>
 document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);function onDeviceReady(){//alert("ondeviceready");}
</script>
```

Comment: Where is the onDeviceReady() function??

Comment: I want to put two javascript file inside onDeviceReady() {  <script src="assets/script1.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/script2.js"></script>} is it possible.

Comment: You need to add the `onDeviceReady()` event handler in your code. Your on the right track, but you can't put HTML tags in JavaScript like that. Copy whats in those .js file into `onDeviceReady`. Look at this example: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/cordova/events/events.html

Comment: you can try this one    =>    document.write("<script src='assets/script1.js'></script>"); document.write("<script src='assets/script2.js'></script>");